# Using the Java Guava library, how to create a ImmutableSortedSet using a Builder?

Tags: java, generics, types, guava, type-inference

I'm sure this is a very simple question but please take a look at the code sample below:

```
final ImmutableSortedSet<String> notOk = ImmutableSortedSet.naturalOrder().build();         
final ImmutableSortedSet<String> ok = new ImmutableSortedSet.Builder<String>(Ordering.natural()).build();
final ImmutableList<String> typicalGuava = ImmutableList.of("one", "two");
```

I'm just wondering what is the proper way to use the naturalOrder() method in the first example? In that example Java cannot infer the type so you get a "type mismatch" error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a series of chained calls like that, the compiler is unable to infer the type argument for the call to `naturalOrder()` since its result is not immediately assigned to something it can use for inference.

You can write

```
ImmutableSortedSet<String> ok = ImmutableSortedSet.<String>naturalOrder().build();
```

or

```
ImmutableSortedSet.Builder<String> builder = ImmutableSortedSet.naturalOrder();
// ...
ImmutableSortedSet<String> ok = builder.build();
```

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
final ImmutableSortedSet<String> nowOk = ImmutableSortedSet.<String>naturalOrder().build();
```