# What do type params for generic methods do?

Tags: java, guava

I am interested why this fragment of code produces a syntax error saying ImmutableMap cannot be resolved to a type:

```
ImmutableMap<String, String> advice = ImmutableMap<String, String>.builder()
                    .put(KEY1, VAL1)
                    .put(KEY2, VAL2)
                    .build();
```

While this code works as intended:

```
ImmutableMap<String, String> advice = ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder()
                    .put(KEY1, VAL1)
                    .put(KEY2, VAL2)
                    .build();
```

The period isn't going where my mental model should and I was hoping someone could explain why the  goes on the "method side" of the period. I'm using Guava's ImmutableMap, but its not entirely relevant I don't think. I think it has something to do with the generics but I'm not sure what and I'm not sure how to search to find a better answer since I don't know what the concept would be called.

EDIT: For reference, [ImmutableMap](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.java#128) has this line for `builder()`

```
public static <K, V> Builder<K, V> builder() {
    return new Builder<K, V>();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/55679/829571

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the Java Guava library, how to create a ImmutableSortedSet using a Builder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362856/using-the-java-guava-library-how-to-create-a-immutablesortedset-using-a-builder)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

builder() is a static method which has generic types associated with it, not the class it is defined in. It will be something like

```
public static <K,V> ImmutableMap.Builder<K,V> builder() { ... }
```

Note: the `<K, V>` here doesn't have anything to do with the generic types of the class. (Which doesn't have to be generic)

Comment: So, I'm trying to piece your answer and the other by @David M together. Because this is a static method and the generic types aren't actually associated with the class when it is loaded a single time into the class loader, the method needs to have type information passed in?

So, when I read the line you posted, should I read it as:
<K, V>ImmutableMap <-- return type | method--><K,V>builder() ? As in the method signature includes the requirements of indicating the generic types?

Comment: Notionally, its the signature of the method which has the generic type. The generic types are not being passed or available at runtime in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way Java implements generics, by type erasure (casting) not expansion, there is actually only one `ImmutableMap` class loaded. Its static `builder` method is what therefore needs resolving to the specific generic overload. The declaring of the variable `advice` as `ImmutableMap<String, String>` is syntactic sugar for the compiler, which then assumes the associated overloads whenever an **instance** method is called on `advice`. But the static method call on `ImmutableMap` must be specified separately. That's why the generics appear on the method side of the dot.

This would be different in a language that implements generics by expansion, like C#, where each generic map type would be loaded as a separate type into the CLR, so `ImmutableMap<String, String>` would be a different type with different static methods to `ImmutableMap<Foo, Bar>`.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to find information about this concept, since it is a little obscure. I had to search Angelika Langer's great Generics FAQ for a while to find it, even though I knew about it...

Anyway, it's called "explicit type argument specification", and it's used when you want to specify the type arguments for a generic method explicitly, usually because the compiler cannot infer it from the context (e.g. when chaining method calls), or because you want to help the compiler choose between various overloads:

http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ402

More info on type argument inference:

http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ400